# I cannot get photoscape 7.3?

Tags: ubuntu

I have tried many times to install http://photoscape.org on here.

Answer (score 1):

This software is for Microsoft Windows and not  compatible with Linux .

You can download it and launch it with [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)

- Download and install Wine : type in Terminal

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y \
      && sudo apt-get update \
      && sudo apt-get install wine
  ```
- Download [PhotoScape](http://photoscape.org/ps/main/download.php) then open the installer using Wine :

Assuming that the downloaded file `PhotoScape_V3.7.exe` is in `Downloads` Directory , type in Terminal :

```
wine ./Downloads/PhotoScape_V3.7.exe
```

then you can find the software in `/home/<YourUserName>/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/PhotoScape`

and you can launch it from dash